# A way to sort files into tibbles based on filename in R?

Tags: r, sorting, append, tibble, file-sorting

I have a large list of files and want to sort columns from certain files in the list into two tibbles. The file names contain the phrases I need to identify which files go where, but I can't figure out an efficient and universal way to do the sorting and appending. All files contain the same columns and column names, but varying numbers of columns. I would prefer tidyverse solutions.
An example of my file names:

```r
A1_SORE6_REEC_T=1.csv
A5_minCMV_noREEC_T=5.csv
```

and the tibbles look something like this, plus a few other columns:

```r
file1 <- tibble(ID = 1:50, Ch1_RawIntDen = sample(1:2000, 50), Ch1_IntDen = sample(1:2000, 50), Ch1_IntNorm = sample(1:2000, 50))
```

I want to be able to filter files by any part, or multiple parts, (A#, SORE6/minCMV, REEC/noREEC, and T=#) of these file names, then extract one column from my filtered files and append them all into one tibble.

I have technically found a way to accomplish this, but it is hideous and very hardcoded. I would also like to be able to filter by multiple phrases within the filename, but right now I can only sort by one phrase. Here is the code I use now, in which I'm grabbing the Ch1_IntNorm column from each file:

```
filelist <- list.files(path = "data-cleaned", full.names = TRUE)

for (x in 1:length(filelist)) {
  if (str_detect(string = filelist[[x]], "SORE6") == TRUE) {
    if (exists("SORE6", envir = ) == FALSE) {
      SORE6 <- read_csv(filelist[[x]], col_select = Ch1_IntNorm)
    } else {
      SORE6 <- rbind(SORE6,read_csv(filelist[[x]], col_select = Ch1_IntNorm))
    }
  } else {
    if (exists("minCMV", envir = ) == FALSE) {
      minCMV <- read_csv(filelist[[x]], col_select = Ch1_IntNorm)
    } else {
      minCMV <- rbind(minCMV, read_csv(filelist[[x]], col_select = Ch1_IntNorm))
    }
  }
  
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to append all the files together without using one file as the starting point, hence the check for an existing variable. You can also see I don't technically grab the "minCMV" files based on their filename, I just define anything that isn't "SORE6" as "minCMV", which will not always be the case going forward.

I want the final tibbles to look something like this:

```r
SORE6 <- tibble(Ch1_IntNorm = sample(1:2000, 200))
```

I'm new to R so I would appreciate an explanation of how any solutions work. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a reproducible example. We do not have access to your file system so we cannot read in the CSVs. You should also post an example of your expected output so we know exactly what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe something like `split(filelist, stringr::str_match(filelist, "^.+_(.+)_")[,2]) |> lapply(readr::read_csv) | list2env()` would work. We split the file list based on a regular expression and then pass those chuncks into `readr::read_csv` which can take a list of file names and merge them into one data.frame for you

Comment: Note that "growing an object" as you do by putting `rbind` inside your loop is a bad practice renowned for slowing down code. You're much better off with Mr Flick's approach, where the files names are classified/split first, and then each batch is read in in one command.

Comment: I tried @MrFlick strategy, with slight modification, and it worked perfectly. I had never used regex before, so that wasn't a strategy I considered. Thank you! This was my ultimate solution: `split(filelist, stringr::str_match(filelist, "^(?=.*SORE6)(?=.*REEC)(?=.*T=1\\B).*$")[,1]) %>% map(readr::read_csv, col_select = Ch1_IntNorm) %>% do.call(rbind,.)`